# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to clone our online WordPress website to localhost (using XAMPP) by following this tutorial: https://looks-awesome.com/copying-live-wordpress-site-localhost

Everything was easy to understand and went smoothly until I tried to load the website. Whenever I try to open index.php or wp-admin I am shown this error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs..." . It references php files for different themes and plugins.

After navigating to the PHP code in question it does indeed seem that the [] operator is being used on strings. Why does this all work fine on our live website but not locally? Is there a way to troubleshoot and fix this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Check the PHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a different version of PHP you are using in your localhost and you are using themes and plugins which are not compatible with php >= 7.1 
As of PHP 7.1, php syntax that previously allowed one to simultaneously create a sub-dimension on an array with a element in that new array is not allowed if that array index was set to a string. 
Downgrade your localhost PHP version to 5.6 and it will work correctly